# Is there detailed documentation somewhere for all the views in the DBC database?

Tags: teradata

I use dbc.tables, dbc.columns, and dbc.indices a lot in the custom utilities I create.  However, I see all kinds of variations of those views.  For example, there's tablesx, tablesv, tablesvx, tables2, etc.  What are all of these?  Which one should I use?  The same goes for the different variations of dbc.columns and dbc.indices.  Does detailed documentation exist that explains what not only these views are for, but all of the other views in DBC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Data Dictionary manual for Teradata 14, Chapter 2, Types of Views explains the various views you find in DBC.

Specifically the X and V Views in DBC:

- V Views are Unicode views that without any conversion of object names
  to Kanji or Latin
- X Views have security constraints limiting the rows to those only associated with the requesting user, such as objects the user owns or
  created and objects user has been granted privileges  -

Tables2 provides information about referential integrity relationships between objects.

Comment: Adding the "which one to use?": Non-V views are deprecated and exist only for legacy applications. X or non-X: Depends on what your allowed to use, DBA can restrict access to non-X views. X-views are much slower, while non-X might will return info about objects where the calling doesn't have any access.